# Contar Filas de un query

Tags: php, mysql

!

Tengo un proyecto conectado a MySQL con PDO y utilizo este código para filtrar filas; se ejecuta mediante un input text y un input submit:

```
if(isset($_POST['btn_search'])){
        $buscar_text=$_POST['search'];
        $select_buscar=$con->prepare('
            SELECT * FROM curso WHERE NOMBRE LIKE :campo OR AREA LIKE :campo;'
        );
        $select_buscar->execute(array(
            ':campo' =>"%".$buscar_text."%"
        ));
        $resultado=$select_buscar->fetchAll();
    }
```

En la misma página, el siguiente código cuenta los registros de la base de datos; se ejecuta al cargar la página mostrando los resultados en un input text, sin embargo cuenta todos los registros de la base de datos y no solo del query realizado.

```
    $sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM curso WHERE NOMBRE = 'Andrea' AND AREA = 'Gramática'"; 
    $result = $con->prepare($sql); 
    $result->execute(); 
    $resultcount = $result->fetchColumn();
```

¿Cómo hago para contar solamente de las filas devueltas del primer Query y no de toda la base de datos?

Muchas Gracias!

Comment: No te estaria entendiendo... el segundo tiene unos filtros estaticos, y el primero tiene filtros que son decididos por el usuario....

Comment: Hola, mil disculpas, no tengo mucha experiencia en programación, no conozco el concepto de filtro estático .... el primer código realiza filtros de la base de datos y quiero que el segundo código realice el COUNT solamente de esas filas devueltas y no de toda la base de datos.

Comment: bueno.. vas a tener que aprender varias cosas... primero, no entiendo el orden en que pasan las cosas en tu pagina, y eso es importante.. despues, no estas contando tu base de datos.. una base de datos es un conjunto de tablas (y otras cosas) pero una tabla (que es lo que consultas aca) no es toda tu base de datos. ahora, vos que queres que cuente? la primera parte que mostras, hace un query cuyos parametros son dinamicos y definidos por el usuario en la pagina... el segundo, hace un query con los mismos parametros siempre...

Comment: El primer query está basado en parámetros ingresados por el usuario, que puede ser por 'NOMBRE' o 'AREA '... el segundo query tendrá siempre los mismos parámetros, pero será aplicado solo en los resultados del primero y no en todos los registros de la tabla 'CURSO' de la base de datos ...  El usuario ingresará un criterio en el primer query ... luego de presionar el botón submit se muestra las FILAS encontradas, después el segundo query automáticamente indicará la cantidad de registros que cumplan con dos criterios estáticos, pero solo aplicándolo en las FILAS encontradas previamente.

Comment: perfecto.. entonces al segundo query, tenes que agregarle los parametros que filtraron el primero... que como van a los mismos campos, pueden generar un resultado un tanto extraño...

Comment: Si lo que quieres es contar los registros que hay aquí: `$resultado=$select_buscar->fetchAll();`, dado que `$resultado` será un array con todas las filas obtenidas, puedes hacer algo así: **`$total=count($resultado);`**  y ya lo tienes, no es necesario que hagas otra consulta para obtener datos que ya están a mano.